# Java filling char matrix from user without space

Tags: for-loop, matrix, char, java.util.scanner, fill

I want to be able to ask the user to fill the matrix. The code works but the problem is that if the user dont enter values with space the output will be wrong.

```
enter code here
    char [][] matrix = new char[2][2];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] =scanner.next().charAt(0);
        }
    };

   // the user can enter with space: 
      a b
      c d
   
 // however when the user enters without space the program dont stop and the matrix dont get filled in the right way:
      ab
      cd

// expected output should fill out the matrix with given values from the user without space.
```

Answer (score 0):

It requires a space with this code because the default delimiter of `Scanner` is whitespace. Meaning that `Scanner` splits up the input at whitespace (like spaces) and `scanner.next()` returns the next chunk. In order to not require spaces, you have to override the default delimiter using

```java
scanner.useDelimiter("");
```

before you call `scanner.next()` (i.e. before the for loops).

Comment: Thx sir! Almost right. I now get the output: [[a,b],[,c]] instead of [[a,b],[c,b]]. And I dont know why when I print the matrix the second half of the matrix end up in the next line